# how to make a random matrix in bash in that program

Tags: bash, shell, matrix, random

```
#!/bin/bash

# How to make a random matrix in bash in that program, 
# I don't understand how to make a random matrix in shell script.


# read the matrix order
read -p "Give rows and columns: " n

# accept elements
echo "Matrix element:"

let i=0
while [ $i -lt $n ]
do
let j=0
while [ $j -lt $n ]
do
read x[$(($n*$i+$j))]
j=$(($j+1))
done
i=$(($i+1))
done
```

Comment: paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: bash doesn't sopport multidim arrays, what are you trying to do?

Comment: The form of the line  . . . read x[$(($n*$i+$j))]  . . . is invalid.  Your logic seems to refer to a symmetric matrix, but that line is prompting the user to manually input a value for a "randomly" assigned index in a one-dimensional matrix.   There is no clear rationale to the program logic, regardless of the stated purpose to create a "random" matrix, while there is NO use of random functions, (i.e. rand or shuf).  Also, bash does not handle muti-dimension matrices, so you need to resort to something like AWK or another language (Python, C, Pascal, Ada) for that capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only looking to **display** numbers arranged as if they were in a n X n matrix, then the following will give you some ideas on how to get the random numbers and passing those to the "formatting" portion of the script.

```
#!/bin/sh

# read the matrix order
read -p "Enter dimension of symmetric matrix: " n

count=$(( $n * $n ))

NUMBERS="./numbers.txt"
shuf -n ${count} --input-range=0-99  >"${NUMBERS}"

# accept elements
echo "Matrix element:"

i=0
while [ $i -lt $n ]
do
    j=0
    while [ $j -lt $n ]
    do
        read pos
        echo "\t${pos}\c"

        j=$(($j+1))
    done
    echo ""
    i=$(($i+1))
done <"${NUMBERS}"
```